# Notification Sound Not Playing In Android

Tags: java, android, notifications

**Creating Notification Channel**
before i create channel i am deleting old channel with channel id.

```
public class App extends Application {

        public static String CHANNEL_ID = "CH1";
        public static String CHANNEL_NAME = "CH1 Channel";

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            createNotificationChannel();
        }

        public void createNotificationChannel() 
        {
            PrefManager prefManager = PrefManager.getPrefManager(this);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
            {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

                Uri defaultUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

                AudioAttributes attr = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();

                if (prefManager.getNotificationSound().equals("Bell")) {
                Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                        + "://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bells);
                channel.setSound(alarmSound, attr);
                } else {
                channel.setSound(defaultUri, attr);
                }

                channel.enableLights(true);
                channel.enableVibration(true);
                assert notificationManager != null;
               //Deleting Notification Channel
                try 
                {
                    notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channel.getId());
                } catch (Exception E) {}
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
         }
    }
```

**Posting Notification by using below.**

```
            Uri defaultUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bells);


            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, App.CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(description)
                    .setContentText(notificationMessageArray[randomIndex])
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_buddha)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                    .setSound((PrefManager.getPrefManager(context).getNotificationSound().equals("Bell") ? alarmSound : defaultUri), AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
                    .build();


            Log.e(TAG, "Posting Notification " + description);

            notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt() * 100, notification);
```

before i create channel i am deleting old channel with channel id. 
I dont know where i am going wrong in this code.

if i remove code of setting sound from channel and notification default sound not playing but other notification has sound!. i tried with changing importent `HIGH` to `DEFAULT` but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

setSound is only set the ringtone. Just add setOnlyAlertOnce(true), so your code will look like this :

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, App.CHANNEL_ID)
    .setContentTitle(description)
    .setContentText(notificationMessageArray[randomIndex])
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_buddha)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
    .setSound((PrefManager.getPrefManager(context).getNotificationSound().equals("Bell") ? alarmSound : defaultUri), AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
    .build();
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) for the detail